# The provided key is not a valid Google API key Ext JS issue

Tags: google-maps, extjs, google-maps-api-2

I got some issue in Google Map api in my project. I didn't handled anything related to this part and it was working fine before today.

[image]

But now, If i run the application, i got this popup msg and after that, the pages that are using google map api aren't working with this error.
[image]

I googled and followed this step.

1) https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/#project:40595208241:access
2) generate a new key
3) copy the new key to the index.htm inside key value

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2.x&amp;key=AIzaSyAJz86xjTce_oqnSTw8MoNaY-13tIx03XU" type="text/javascript">       </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="extJS-ux/GMapPanel.js"></script>
<link href="extJS-ux/Ext.ux.grid.RowActions.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyAJz86xjTce_oqnSTw8MoNaY-13tIx03XU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('search', '1');
</script>
```

So i've followed this same step, but now it doesn't work anymore. It doesn't show the error msg anymore, but it doesn't also show up the result. It says no result and do nothing. It worked right yesterday!!

I tried to do some other ways, but there wasn't a good solution for this.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using v=2.x (the "experimental version).  That is not recommended for production sites.  It might start working if you call for v=2 or v=2.s (the "stable" version), if this was a change in the API.

Note that you are using [v2 of the Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference) which is deprecated and may stop working May 19, 2013; definitely not recommended for production sites.